# How to wait for the page to fully load using webbrowser method?

Tags: python

```
import webbrowser, sys, time
import pyautogui

print("Googling...")
googleSearch = "+".join(sys.argv[1:])

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://google.com/?q=%s"%googleSearch)
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Enter button is pressed")
    pyautogui.typewrite(["enter"])
else:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.google.com/")
```

This is a basic program to open a google search through the command prompt. Sometimes, the page takes a while to load and thus the enter button will be pressed before it's fully loaded. Using `time.sleep()` works most times when the loading takes a while but is there a more efficient way to do this? I know `selenium` has some explicit wait method but selenium takes a little long to open a page and it's a little impractical to open a google search on a new browser.

Comment: You can't. The `webbrowser` module is a dead-simple tool that can't do anything besides ask the user's browser to open a tab or window (and return immediately without telling you what happened).

Comment: You're already using `pyautogui`. If you use _it_ to drive the browser, you can do whatever you want. But it can't really know when the browser is actually done loading, because there's no way to see that from outside the program.

Comment: You could instead drive the browser with `selenium`, as you already know. Or write a Greasemonkey-style script installed in the browser that communicates the internal "done" callback in some way that `pyautogui` can recognize. Or embed a browser instead of using the user's normal browser, or probably various other things that are even more difficult…

Answer (score 1):

You could use the google `search` endpoint, so you don't need to click enter in the search box on the main page of google

```
safe_search = urllib.parse.quote_plus(search_term)
webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://google.com/search?q={}".format(safe_search)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help.

I use the logo to detect if the website is already loaded.
But could be anything, a button, etc.

```
url = 'https://site'

webbrowser.open(url)

while True:
    logo = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('logo.png')
    if logo is not None:
        break

print logo
```