# How do I wait until a webpage is loaded before opening another tab

Tags: python, web, python-webbrowser

I've made this little python script to automate opening the websites I need in the morning, take a look `

## Required Modules

```
import webbrowser
```

## Open the websites

```
`webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('https://www.netflix.com')
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('https://www.facebook.com')
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab('https://www.udemy.com') `
```

And I don't know how to wait until the webpage is loaded before opening the next one (in another tab), any help?

Comment: Firefox supports this natively. You can set multiple pages to be your homepages, and those will open when you open firefox. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-set-the-home-page

Answer (score 1):

You could take the approach as mentioned at [How to wait for the page to fully load using webbrowser method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807107/how-to-wait-for-the-page-to-fully-load-using-webbrowser-method)  and check for a certain element in the page manually.

Another options would be to `import time` and call it after opening each tab `time.sleep(5)` which waits for 5 seconds before running the next line of code.

```
import webbrowser
from time import sleep

links = ['https://www.netflix.com', 'https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.udemy.com']

for link in links:
    webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab(link)
    sleep(5)
```

Selenium Implementation:

**Note**: This implemenetation opens your URL's in multiple windows rather than a single window and multiple tabs.

I will be using the chrome driver which you can install at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) #this is just to keep the windows open even after the script is done running.

urls = ['https://www.netflix.com', 'https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.udemy.com']

def open_url(url):
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath('chromedriver'), chrome_options=chrome_options)
  # I've assumed the chromedriver is installed in the same directory as the script. If not, mention the path to the chromedriver executable here.
  driver.get(url) 

for url in urls:
  open_url(url)
```

Comment: I tried that out but the internet connection takes more time sometimes and i could make it sleep for 10 seconds to guarantee that it's fully loaded but I'd rather make something like:
if webPageIsLoaded == True:
    open the next webpage

Comment: I haven't worked with the webbrowser library much, so as far as I know there is no built in function to do that in webbrowser. You could use selenium. When you use the selenium webdriver the script waits until the page is finished loading. However, opening multiple tabs is something that I have not been able to do using selenium (multiple windows is possible). There is a probably a JavaScript workaround for that. If you want the code for the selenium implementation let me know

Comment: Yes i would like to get that code, thanks for your help mate

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if you have any queries.