# Pyautogui clicks the button but there is no action?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hi all so basically I’m new to python and using pyautogui

I have been able to do basic operations like moving the mouse to the specified coordinates

**The problem**

Pyautogui clicks on the button which is (Start learning Java now >>) on w3 school website.

I want it to click and move to the next page but apparently, it clicks but there is no action.

in the ideal situation,  it should click the button and move on to the next page but it doesn't do it although I see the click

Since I'm new to Python in general coming from a non-coding background.

I would love to have some opinion on this and a possible workaround

My operating system is Windows and my laptop is a Lenovo yoga s730

Below is the script/code Im using:

```py
import pyautogui
import webbrowser
import time
webbrowser.open("https://www.w3schools.com/java/")
pyautogui.tripleClick(x = 700, y= 783)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to perform the click before the page has fully loaded, your code is quite correct, try this I hope it helps:

```
import pyautogui
import webbrowser
import time

webbrowser.open("https://www.w3schools.com/java/")
time.sleep(5) # wait for the page to load
pyautogui.click(700, 783)
```

if you would like to use some clever workaround the loading time use something like the concept refered to in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672841/13770671

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. I will try this code when I get back to my workspace. 
I also had another question is there any way to get the (x,y) coordinates of a particular button without trial and error. To find the coordinates pyautogui. click(700, 783) which is the button, I had to do a lot of  guessing and I was thinking if there is a way to find them without being tedious Thanks a lot

Comment: If your project is limited to the web, i advice you to use selenium rather than pyautogui
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Sure my project is indeed limited to the web but Im just getting the hangaround of pyautogui and once I get better I will move to selenium for the webproject                                                    
                                                                                                      
 .I was just thinking if there was actually a way to somehow easily find coordinates (x.y) without too much trial and error though?

Comment: Yes, try using the image of the button you're looking for, and use `coords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('button.jpg')` and pass this to your click method `pyautogui.click(coords)`

Comment: See also the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) for more